# $\sigma(n) \equiv 1 \space \pmod{n}$ if and only if $n$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisor-sum

> For $n>1$, let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of all positive integers that evenly divide $n$. Then $\sigma(n) ≡ 1 \space(mod\space n)$ if and only if $n$ is prime.

I've been trying to prove this for a long time, but i can't figure it out.

---

I found a theorem that might be helpful:

> $\sigma(n) = n + k$  has finitely many solutions for $k > 1$ (more specifically, this equation has no solutions for $n≥k^2$).

proof:

> let  $n≥k^2>1,\space \sigma(n) = n + k$. Note that $n$ must be a composite number (otherwise $k=1$). Therefore, $n$ has a divisor $d≥\sqrt n$. From $\sigma(n)$'s definition:
>
> $\sigma(n) ≥ n+d+1≥n+\sqrt n + 1 ≥ n + k + 1 > n + k$

If anyone can generalize this to $\sigma(n)=qn+k$, or something like that, it might help.

Comment: Can you prove it in one of the directions? Have you worked some small numerical examples to see what's going on? Try all the numbers up to $17$.

Comment: Isn't $n=1$ a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, you can conclude it by finding a formula for sigma(p^k), and then using the fact that sigma(n*k) =sigma (n)*sigma(k) for gcd(n,k)=1

Comment: @paw88789 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: One direction is obvious. The second direction I can't figure out

Comment: All n except for 1

Comment: @C.Oliveira.  Right, but $\sigma(1)\equiv 1 (mod 1)$

Comment: @paw88789 Oh, now I know what you mean. You're right.

Comment: i've checked all numbers up to 2,000,000 and it seems to be right

Comment: This is a very nice question (if the answer eventually is "yes")

Comment: anyone that thinks this is a good question, please vote.

Comment: Apparently, it is known that this is true, but I have seen no proof yet. This is mentioned [in this book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=yBLeBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%CF%83(n)+%3D+n+%2B+1+%22prime%22&source=bl&ots=DvHsLErL-h&sig=kXoiGp1-Ifkuva1daHXVxIMAuWc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmye6L6rLZAhUGh5AKHYqFADQ4ChDoAQglMAA#v=onepage&q=%CF%83(n)%20%3D%20n%20%2B%201%20%22prime%22&f=false).

Comment: Any number $n>1$ has at least two factors: 1 and $n$. So the result would seem to be false.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: One way is obvious, if $p$ is prime, then obviously $p\mid \sigma (p) -1 = p$. The other way is a mystery :(

Comment: anyone that has a 'good' lead, or something they think is important and want to share, write your comment in the form of an answer so we could see it clearly.

Comment: Have you tried using the chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Notice $m \equiv z \mod MN \implies m\equiv z \mod M$.  And notice that $\sigma (mk) = \sigma(k)\sigma(m)$  and notice for primes $p, q$ that $\sigma(p^2) \not \equiv 1\mod p^2$ and $\sigma(pq)\not \equiv 1\mod pq$.  Thus if $\sigma(n= p^2*M)\not\ equiv 1 \mod n$ and $\sigma(n=pq*N)\not \equiv 1 \mod n$.  So if $n$ is composite $\sigma n \not \equiv 1 \mod n$.

Comment: @C.Oliveira I can't open that book that you mention but I'd be surprised if that question was settled - see answer below.

Comment: @C.Oliveira The book says that $\sigma(n) = n+1$ if and only if $n$ is prime, which is obvious. The question been discussed here is much more interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a hard problem.

If you can prove your conjecture, then it will imply immediately that there are no [quasi-perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number). The existence of quasi-perfect numbers is a long-open problem.

Answer (score -5):

If $p$ is prime then the only number that divide $p$ are $1$ and $p$ so $\sigma (p) = 1 + p \equiv 1 \mod p$.

So that's one direction.

Let $\sigma(n)=1$ .

If $\sigma(n) \equiv 1 \mod n$ and if $k|n$ then $\sigma (n) \equiv 1 \mod \frac nk$ (because if $n|\sigma(n) -1$ and $\frac nk|n$ then $\frac nk|\sigma(n) -1$.)

Now $\sigma(n) = $ sum of all factors that are multiples of $\frac nk$ plus all the multiples that are not multiples of  $\frac nk $.

All the multiples that are not multiples of  $\frac nk =\sigma(\frac nk)$.

So $\sigma(n) \equiv \sigma(\frac nk) \mod \frac nk$.

So $\sigma(\frac nk)\equiv 1 \mod \frac nk$.

So by induction.

$\sigma(pq) \equiv 1 \mod pq$ where $p\ne q$ but $pq|n$ and $\sigma(p^2) \equiv 1 \mod p^2$ where $p^2|n$.

We can show these are impossible.  $\sigma(p^2) = 1 + p + p^2 \equiv 1+p \mod p^2$ and as $1 < 1+ p < p^2$ that is not equivalent to $1$.

If $pq|n$ and $p\ne q$ wolog assume $p\le 2  < q$ then $\sigma(pq) = 1 + p + q + pq \equiv 1+p + q \mod pq$.  But $1+p + q \le q + q \le pq$.  Equality can only hold if $p = 2$ and $q=3$ and in that case $1+ 2 + 3\equiv 0 \mod 6$.

So... these are contradictions.  It's not possible that $n$ has two or more unequal prime factors, and it is not possible that $n$ have any prime factor to a power higher than $1$ as a factor.

In other words, $n$ must be prime.

Comment: I didn't really get your answer. Can someone explain?

Comment: If you "don't get" an answer, then don't accept it Ido.

Comment: Someone explained it at the top

Comment: If $k|n $ then $n $ has two types of factors: those that are multiples of $k $ and those which are not.  The ones that aren't multiples of $k $ are factors of $n/k $ (actually that's not entirely true-- but it's fixable if I specify $\gcd (n/k, k)=1$) if you add up the factors that are not multiples $k $ those are the factors of $n/k $.  So the sum is $\sigma (n/k) $.  But I think I made an error if k isn't prime.

Comment: In your argument $\sigma(n) \equiv \sigma(n/k) \mod n/k$, you didn't use the assumption that $\sigma(n) \equiv 1 \mod n$, as far as I see. And as such, it is definitely wrong (take $n = 12, k = 3$). We have $\sigma(12) = 28 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ but $\sigma(4) = 7 \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

Comment: The point is for $\sigma (nk)=1\mod nk$ then $\sigma (n)=1\mod n$ and  it isn't possible for $\sigma (pq)=1\mod pq $ and $\sigma (p^k)=1\mod p^k $ so $\sigma (nk)=1\mod nk $ is impossible.  I do have an error though.

Comment: If $n$ and $k$ are two coprime integers, we have $\sigma(nk) = \sigma(k) + \sigma(n)  - 1$. If, additionally, $k$ is prime, this simplifies to $\sigma(nk) = k + \sigma(n)$. Hence, if $\sigma(nk) = 1 \mod nk$, then $\sigma(nk) = 1 \mod n$ and so $\sigma(n) = 1 - k \mod n$. We can find aribtrary large $n$, such that there exist a prime $k < n$ that is not a divisor of $n$. For any such $n$, $\sigma(nk)  - \sigma(n)$ can therefore *never* be a multiple of $n$.

Comment: If anyone has an answer, write it in answer format

Comment: @fleablood what is wrong is when you say that all factors of $n$ are either multiples of $n/k$ of factors of $n/k$ (implied when you say that the non-multiples add up to $\sigma(n/k)$). You could have some of the prime factors in $n/k$ but not all. In any case it is unlikely that a simple proof will work - see my answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right that I have an error there.