# Cool riddle involving integer vectors

Tags: vectors, puzzle, integers

Let $V$ be a $k$-dimensional vector ($k$ is given) of the form $$V=[n_1, n_2, ..., n_k],$$

where $n_1, n_2, ..., n_k$ are positive integers.

Your objective is to determine $V$ by choosing $T$ vectors of your choice, and receiving their dot products with $V$ respectively.

for example, if my vector is $[1, 2]$, and your vectors are $[1, 1], [5, 3/2]$, you will get their dot poducts: $([1,1]*[1,2] =3, [5,3/2]*[1,2] = 8)$

> What is the minimum number of vectors $T$ that you need to choose to determine $V$? (bonus: add the requirement that your vectors must consist of positive integers as well)

(p.s. there exists a solution $T<k$, it's not that obvious)

The solution to this riddle(s) is amazing, and i'll post it in a couple of days.

Comment: The number of vectors $T$ is meant to be minimum in a absolute sense (i.e. given **any** vector $V$ of positive integer, you can figure out it using exactly $t$ vectors $T$), or minimum in **average** (i.e. in the average of **a lot of possible vectors** $V$, which is the minimum number of vectors $T$)?

Comment: Your "riddle" needs some clarification. Does this game involve rounds where I submit a vector and you respond with a dot product or do I have to send you all my vectors at once?

Comment: the first option (minimum T in an absolute sense)

Comment: you know what dot product was produced by each vector you gave me, so it's as if you send me them one by one.

Comment: @IdoFraenkel: Your comment doesn't answer my question. In a game of questions, it makes a great deal of difference if I have to design all my questions in advance or whether I can use the answers to earlier questions to help me design the next question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't understand your question. I originally meant that you design your 'questions in advance, but you can solve for both cases (the answer doesn't change anyway, as arnaud has shown below.

Comment: @IdoFraenkel: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: $[1, 10^k, 10^{2k}, 10^{3k}, 10^{4k}, 10^{5k}, 10^{6k}, ...]$ for sufficiently large $k$, and then read the vector right off the dot product (in reverse). To maximize the wear on the questioner's patience let $k=10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}}}$ or so and assume they haven't put any larger numbers in the vector.

Comment: You're almost right, but you can't just assume that k is sufficiently large. Write your answer in an answer format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If any real numbers are allowed then $ T=1 $: choose the vector $(e, e^2,\ldots , e^n) $ and use the fact that $ e $ is transcendental. It is not constructive but you know that different vectors will output different dot products.

**Edit:** if $(a_1,\ldots, a_n) $ and $(b_1,\ldots, b_n) $ are two vectors that output the same number,  then $ e $ is a root of the polynomial with integer coefficients $$\sum (a_i -b_i) X^i$$ therefore all its coefficients are zero.

Comment: Nice answer: I wonder whether it will be the right one when the OP eventually gives all the necessary information.

Comment: it's not that answer i had in mind but it is still correct. i think my solution is a bit better so stick around! meanwhile you can solve the bonus question, and maybe explain why your answer is correct in further detail.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder too if one could find a constructivist solution with $ T=1 $.

Comment: i don't exactly know what you mean by 'constructive', but if it is what i think it is then my answer is a constructive solution.

Comment: You don't even need transcendental numbers, just any numbers that are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, e.g. square roots of distinct primes.

Comment: @IdoFraenkel How is a solution using $T=2$ *better* than this? The problem was asking for a minimum.

Comment: This is the answer to the bonus question (Wich adds the requirement that your vector consists only of positive integers), and the correct solution to that question is T=2. This solution addresses the first question, and it is correct, but it is not a 'perfect' answer and not the solution I had in mind

Answer (score 6):

If $V$ were limited to entries at most $b$, then the solution would be easy: query
$$ V \cdot [b^0, b^1, \dots, b^{k-1}]$$
The result, when read in base-$b$, would be the vector $V$. However, this would be foiled for any constant choice of $b$ because the entries of $V$ could be arbitrarily large. (Any scheme to "guess" such a $b$, for example, by repeatedly doubling, could be similarly fooled).

However, it's easy to get a $b$ large enough: $V \cdot [1, 1, \dots, 1]$ is the sum of the entries in $V$. Since all of the entries in $V$ are strictly positive, this dot product is strictly bigger than any entry in $V$ (as it's the sum of the largest element and the rest of the elements, which are at least 1).

Thus, the first query is $b = V \cdot [1, 1, 1, \dots, 1]$.

The second query is $v = V \cdot [b^0, b^1, b^2, \cdots, b^{k-1}]$.

Then $V$ is the result from reading the digits of $v$ in base-$b$, so $t \leq 2$.

(Since any number of vectors have the same dot product, $t \geq 2$ so this does give $t = 2$ exactly)

---

This relies heavily on the positiveness of the entries of $V$. Can the problem be solved in fewer than $k$ queries when the entries of $V$ are allowed to be negative?

---

I remember a very similar problem, that tasks you with determining the coefficients of a polynomial $q$ with only non-negative integer as coefficients with as few integer queries as possible. (The method looks about the same as this problem).

[A link to a blog post concerning this problem is here.](https://jeremykun.com/2014/11/18/learning-a-single-variable-polynomial-or-the-power-of-adaptive-queries/)

Comment: This is exactly my solution

Comment: Cross-site polynomial version link: [A secret polynomial](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25922/a-secret-polynomial)

Comment: I think that the second query must be: $$v = V \cdot [(b+1)^0, (b+1)^1, (b+1)^2, \cdots, (b+1)^{k-1}].$$ If the maximum number is $b$, then you want to represent the hidden vector in base $b+1$...

Comment: Since the entries of $V$ are strictly positive (and I'm assuming there are at least two, otherwise this is trivial), $b$ will be at least one more than the largest element, so $b+1$ is not necessary. However, my explanation there was lacking, I'll update it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my answer:

Let $I = [ln(2),ln(3),...,ln(p_k)]$ where $p_k$ is the $k^{th}$ prime.

$V*I=n_1ln(2)+n_2ln(3)+...+n_kln(p_k) = ln(2^{n_1}*3^{n_2}*...*p_k^{n_k})$

Therefore, by taking the prime factorizations of $e^{V*I}$, and looking at the exponents, we can deduce what $V$ is.

So by choosing $I$ and only $I$ to be our vector, we can fully deduce $V$ (and $minT=1$).

Comment: please help me solve this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2657374/532929

Answer (score 1):

I would choose $T = k$ vectors $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$, which are linearly independent.

Then, I would create a matrix $A$ which rows corresponds to each vector $a_i$. For construction, $A$ is invertible.

Moreover, given $q_i$ as the dot product of $V$ with $a_i$, I create the column vector $q = [q_1 ~ q_2 ~ \ldots ~ q_k]^\top.$

Finally, I can calculate $V$ as follows:

$$V = A^{-1}q.$$

Additionally, I can avoid the inversion of matrix $A$ if I choose $a_i$ as versors, i.e. $a_i$ has only $0$ components, and the $i$-th entry is $1$. In this case, $A$ is the identity matrix, and I obtain that:

$$q_i = n_i.$$

Comment: Nice, but you did 't use the fact that v consists of positive integers. There is a better solution with t<k

Comment: @IdoFraenkel when $k=2$, I would say that you can't do better than $2$, right? So maybe you mean $t$ vectors such that $t \leq k$?

Comment: as @ArnaudMortier has shown below, it is possible using T = 1

Comment: but for the bonus question you are correct

Comment: if you choose $k$ vectors anyway, wouldn 't you take the $k$ unit vectors to obtain $V$ componentwise?

Comment: @collapsar yes, this is what I wrote at the end of my answer ("Additionally, ...")